# Can't simulate an XHR request to a PowerBI dashboard

Tags: r, post, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, httr

I'm trying to scrape some data from a PowerBI dashboard but for some reason I'm not able to replicate an XHR request successfully. Here are the details of the original request taken from Chrome web inspector:

**Request**

```
Request URL: https://wabi-west-europe-api.analysis.windows.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 51.144.73.151:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Headers**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,sl;q=0.4
ActivityId: b3b20ea3-8f93-1848-b4be-ebf1a5c0952f
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1176
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: wabi-west-europe-api.analysis.windows.net
Origin: https://app.powerbi.com
Referer: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiM2MxY2RkMTQtOTA3Mi00MDIxLWE1NDktZjlmYTdlNDg0MTdkIiwidCI6IjhkZDFlNmI0LThkYWMtNDA4ZS04ZDhkLTY3NTNlOTgwMDUzMCIsImMiOjl9
RequestId: 70c90610-a020-7191-a0fe-91b74d0407b9
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
X-PowerBI-ResourceKey: 3c1cdd14-9072-4021-a549-f9fa7e48417d
```

**Request body**

```
{"version":"1.0.0","queries":[{"Query":{"Commands":[{"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand":{"Query":{"Version":2,"From":[{"Name":"q","Entity":"LastRefresh","Type":0}],"Select":[{"Aggregation":{"Expression":{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"q"}},"Property":"Date Last Refreshed"}},"Function":3},"Name":"Min(Query1.Date Last Refreshed)"}]},"Binding":{"Primary":{"Groupings":[{"Projections":[0]}]},"DataReduction":{"DataVolume":3,"Primary":{"Top":{}}},"Version":1}}}]},"CacheKey":"{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"q\",\"Entity\":\"LastRefresh\",\"Type\":0}],\"Select\":[{\"Aggregation\":{\"Expression\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"q\"}},\"Property\":\"Date Last Refreshed\"}},\"Function\":3},\"Name\":\"Min(Query1.Date Last Refreshed)\"}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0]}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Top\":{}}},\"Version\":1}}}]}","QueryId":"","ApplicationContext":{"DatasetId":"ec162a68-e319-4018-8364-d2a74d3ed429","Sources":[{"ReportId":"8ef2e9f7-0417-4e8f-bd02-f7a3ee0fedd2"}]}}],"cancelQueries":[],"modelId":3563760}
```

For my simulated request I use:

```
httr::POST("https://wabi-west-europe-api.analysis.windows.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true", content_type_json(), add_headers(.headers = heads), body = payload) %>% content()
```

to perform the request. As headers I only used: 'X-PowerBI-ResourceKey', 'RequestId', 'ActivityId', 'Referer'. Payload is the json copied from the Request body. I get this response:

```
$error
$error$code
[1] "BadRequest"

$error$message
[1] "Bad Request"

$error$details
$error$details[[1]]
$error$details[[1]]$message
[1] "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: C. Path 'queries[0].CacheKey', line 1, position 488."

$error$details[[1]]$target
[1] "request.queries[0].CacheKey"


$error$details[[2]]
$error$details[[2]]$message
[1] "'request' is a required parameter"

$error$details[[2]]$target
[1] "request"
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

UDPATE:

solved with a change of approach in [Correct way to get response body of XHR requests generated by a page with RStudio Chromote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000659/correct-way-to-get-response-body-of-xhr-requests-generated-by-a-page-with-rstudi)