# Correct way to get response body of XHR requests generated by a page with RStudio Chromote

Tags: r, web-scraping, headless-browser, chrome-devtools-protocol, crrri

I'd like to use Chromote to gather the response body of the XHR calls made by a website, but I find the API a bit complex to master, especially the async pipeline.

I guess I need to first enable the Network functionality and then load the page (this can do), but then I need to:

- list all XHR calls
- filter them by recognizing patterns in the request URL
- access the request body of the selected sources

Can someone provide any guidance or tutorial material on this regard?

UPDATE:
Ok, I switched to package `crrri` and made a general function for the purpose. The only missing part is some logic to decide when to close the connection and return the results:

```
get_website_resources <- function(url, url_filter = '*', type_filter = '*') {
  library(crrri)
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)
  library(jsonlite)
  library(magrittr)

  chrome <- Chrome$new()
  
  out <- new.env()
  
  out$l <- list()
  
  client <- chrome$connect(callback = ~ NULL)
  
  Fetch <- client$Fetch
  Page <- client$Page
  
  Fetch$enable(patterns = list(list(urlPattern="*", requestStage="Response"))) %...>% {
    Fetch$requestPaused(callback = function(params) {
      
      if (str_detect(params$request$url, url_filter) & str_detect(params$resourceType, type_filter)) {
        
        Fetch$getResponseBody(requestId = params$requestId) %...>% {
          resp <- .
          
          if (resp$body != '') {
            if (resp$base64Encoded) resp$body = base64_dec(resp$body) %>% rawToChar()
            
            body <- list(list(
              url = params$request$url,
              response = resp
            )) %>% set_names(params$requestId)
            
            str(body)
            
            out$l <- append(out$l, body)
          }
          
        }
      }
      
      Fetch$continueRequest(requestId = params$requestId)
    })
  } %...>% {
    Page$navigate(url)
  }
  
  
  out$l
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cracked it. Here's the final function. It uses a `crrri::perform_with_chrome` wich force synch behaviour and run the rest of the process into a `promise` object with a `resolve` callback defined outside the promise itself which is called either if a number of resources are collected or if a certain amount of time has passed:

```
get_website_resources <- function(url, url_filter = '*', type_filter = '*', wait_for = 20, n_of_resources = NULL, interactive = F) {

    library(crrri)
    library(promises)

    crrri::perform_with_chrome(function(client) {
        Fetch <- client$Fetch
        Page <- client$Page

        if (interactive) client$inspect()

        out <- new.env()

        out$results <- list()
        out$resolve_function <- NULL

        out$pr <- promises::promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            out$resolve_function <- resolve

            Fetch$enable(patterns = list(list(urlPattern="*", requestStage="Response"))) %...>% {
                Fetch$requestPaused(callback = function(params) {

                    if (str_detect(params$request$url, url_filter) & str_detect(params$resourceType, type_filter)) {

                        Fetch$getResponseBody(requestId = params$requestId) %...>% {
                            resp <- .

                            if (resp$body != '') {
                                if (resp$base64Encoded) resp$body = jsonlite::base64_dec(resp$body) %>% rawToChar()

                                body <- list(list(
                                    url = params$request$url,
                                    response = resp
                                )) %>% set_names(params$requestId)

                                #str(body)

                                out$results <- append(out$results, body)

                                if (!is.null(n_of_resources) & length(out$results) >= n_of_resources) out$resolve_function(out$results)
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    Fetch$continueRequest(requestId = params$requestId)
                })
            } %...>% {
                Page$navigate(url)
            } %>% crrri::wait(wait_for) %>%
                then(~ out$resolve_function(out$results))

        })

        out$pr$then(function(x) x)
    }, timeouts = max(wait_for + 3, 30), cleaning_timeout = max(wait_for + 3, 30))
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for answering your own question.  It helped me clean up a similar bit of code.  Any reason why you chose to bypass the url filtering functionality of `Filter$enable` and reimplement it later in the code?